# Convert list of list and list to csv in python

Tags: python, list, csv

I have been trying to get `list`of`list` and `list` to be written on same row on `csv` in python.

```
d=[[1,2,3,4,5,6],[2,3,4,5,6,7]]
timestamp = [0.1, 0.3] # Basically timestamping for each list of d
file = open('test.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',',lineterminator='\n')
writer.writerows(zip(d, timestamp))
```

But I am getting

```
col1         , col2
[1,2,3,4,5,6], 0.1
[2,3,4,5,6,7], 0.3
```

instead I want to save my `csv` as follows:

```
col1,col2, ...,col7
1,2,3,4,5,6, 0.1
2,3,4,5,6,7, 0.3
```

Please any can help me with this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add each item from the `timestamp` to the corresponding sublist in `d`:

```
>>> [x+[y] for x, y in zip(d, timestamp)]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0.1], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0.3]]
```

And your code becomes:

```
...
writer.writerows(x+[y] for x, y in zip(d, timestamp))
```

In Python 3, you can use **extended unpacking** without having to create the inner list:

```
>>> [x+y for x, *y in zip(d, timestamp)]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0.1], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0.3]]
```

Comment: Thank you. One little thing if I want `timestamp` in the `1st` column than, what sort of change is required?

Comment: You can swap the order of the parameters: `[x+y for *x, y in zip(timestamp, d)]`

Comment: Thank you. But what is to be done for Python 2.7? Cause I have tried `writer.writerows([x+[y] for x, y in zip(t,d)])` still it produce me error as `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'list'`

Comment: Extended unpacking does not work in Python 2.7. This should do: `[[x]+y for x, y in zip(timestamp, d)]`

Answer (score 0):

a slightly different way to unpack your lists is this:

```
writer.writerows((*a, b) for a, b in zip(d, timestamp))
```

this will iterate over the rows

```
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0.1)
(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0.3)
```

(but basically the same idea as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45591244/4954037))